# Changing the style of a single section

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering

I'm trying to change the format of a single section in my document.

The section is the introduction of my document, and therefore, I don't want it to be numbered.

I tried to define a new command

```
\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{%
  \section[#1]{\centering\normalfont\scshape #1}}
```

it works, however, I can't suppress the numbering.

Comment: is there any reason you can't just use `\section*`?

Comment: I don't see why the section shouldn't be numbered, but I can understand if one wants it; however the heading should be in the same style as the others. So `\section*` with `\addcontentsline` should be all you need.

Answer (score 8):

With the help of the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package you can define a command containing the format for special section(s) and another one for regular section(s) and change the formatting as required:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand\specialsection{%
  \titleformat*{\section}{\centering\scshape\Large}
}
\newcommand\regularsection{%
  \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
}

\begin{document}

\specialsection
\section*{Introduction}

\regularsection
\section{A Test Section} 
\section{Another Test Section} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to only specify `\specialsection`, without (re)defining `\regularsection`? Problem is that one needs then to know how "regular sections" are defined? Did you use here the plain standard definition? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\section*` to set an unnumbered section. However, this also removes it from the ToC. To reinsert it, use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{<name>}`, like in the following minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{Introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Another section} \lipsum[11-20]
\section{Yet another section} \lipsum[21-30]
\end{document}
```

The same would hold for other document classes (like `book` and `report`).

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used to generate dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Comment: The question is not only about suppressing the section numbering; the section formatting also has to be changed.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: "Formatting" may be ambiguously used here. Depending on the users, `\section*` "formats" `\section` differently.

Comment: True, but if you look at the code snippet in the question, you'll see an attempt to center the title and a font change.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Oh...