# Defining a custom section command minimum example

Tags: macros

I am trying to define a custom section/paragraph command. In this command I want to reserve some vertical space, and disable the runin of the next paragraph.

When defining a command:

```tex
\newcommand\stars{\@startsection {stars}{1}{\z@}%
           {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
           {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
           {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

I end up with an error regarding a *spacefactor*. What is the minimum example to achieve this?

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m {}
l.518 \stars
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't you customise with `titlesec` instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: I want to have different behavior for the invocation of a section with style1 to styleN, but retain the other properties such as being used for the TOC.

Comment: Looking at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58203/changing-the-style-of-a-single-section the example shows that you would change the style of the section by adding a command in front of it. I am looking for command variants that make them explicit, and directly usable, without having to 'reset' them later.

Comment: You can use `titleformat` and `\titlespacing` within the document, and further, you can define new levels. Could you be more explicit as to what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause seemed to be missing *makeatletter* and *makeatother*.

```tex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\stars{\@startsection {stars}{1}{\z@}%
           {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
           {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
           {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```